# Refresh Datagrid when Datacontext changes

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpfdatagrid

How can i refresh  `Datagrid` when `Datacontext` changes from another page?
I tried `datacontextchanged` and `sourceupdated` handlers. but not working....

Comment: you can pass your window in the constructor of the other windows and then you can fill your datagrid

Comment: if your binding is in place, data grid will automatically update itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to go round and round and try refreshing when something happens. You are using WPF therefore just use `ObservableCollection` as your `DataContext` for your grid. Whenever the `ObservableCollection` Changes your UI will update automatically

[MSDN - ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @user3248559 what diffrence does it make? What ever data structure you are getting from your database / data provider, just convert it to an `ObservableCollection` and use it as `DataContext`. `ObservableCollection` has an event called `CollectionChanged` which fires when... well, when the collection changes... WPF's UI knows whether it needs to refresh based on this event (You can even register to it in order to add extra functionality!)

Comment: namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class customercontext4 : DbContext
    {
        
        public DbSet<customer> customerse3 { get; set; }
    }
}